# How to disable extension button in QToolBar?

Tags: c++, qt, qtoolbar

I would like to know how to disable **extension button** in **QToolBar**, which appears as the last item in the toolbar, when a toolbar is too small to show all the items? I've trying through find child method, but that doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean *disable*?

Comment: @eyllanesc I mean that this button doesn't appear, when the toolbar is too small to display all the elements. For example, button->hide() or setEnabled(false). In Qt Docs I didn't find any information about this.

Comment: I still don't understand you, do you want to hide or want to show that button? What do you mean *small toolbar*?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to hide that button. Small toolbar is when it doesn't fit the width of the window in which it's located, when this window is reduced in width. I have buttons (actions) in this toolbar, and when the toolbar doesn't fit the width of the window, extension button appears in which my buttons are transferred.

Comment: If you want to hide the button then use my solution, if you still have problems then provide a [MRE], in addition to an image of your current problem and what you want to get in order to better understand your problem.

Comment: I'll try it tommorow, thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the button that allows you to expand the QToolBar you must first obtain it using the objectName "qt_toolbar_ext_button", and to hide it you must set to size 0, 0 since the hide() method will fail:

```cpp
if(QToolButton *button = toolbar->findChild<QToolButton *>("qt_toolbar_ext_button")){
    button->setFixedSize(0, 0);
    // button->setEnabled(false);
}
```